# How to show recently used programs in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working on a C# WPF application, and I would like to show a list of recently used programs in my application's user interface. I have a ListBox control where I want to display the program names. However, I'm not sure how to populate the ListBox with the list of recently used programs.

Here is the relevant code I have in my MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Windows.Shell;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
using Syncfusion.Presentation;
using Syncfusion.Presentation.Drawing;


namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private DateTime _lastLoginTime;
        private List<string> _lastUsedPrograms;
        private readonly SpeechSynthesizer _speechSynthesizer;
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        private string _accessToken;
        private string _trackName;
        private string _artistName;
        private TimeSpan? _songDuration;
        private BitmapImage _songImage;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string recentProgramsKey = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs";
            RegistryKey recentProgramsRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(recentProgramsKey);
            string[] recentPrograms = recentProgramsRegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames();

            recentProgramsListBox.ItemsSource = null;

            // Filter the list to show only applications
            // Filter the list to show only applications
            var applicationExtensions = new[] { ".exe" };
            var filteredPrograms = recentPrograms
                .Where(program => applicationExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(program)))
                .Select(program =>
                {
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent), program);
                    string programName = DecodeProgramName(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), 0);
                    return new RecentProgram
                    {
                        FileName = program,
                        FilePath = filePath,
                        ProgramName = programName
                    };
                })
                .ToArray();


            // Bind the filtered list of recently used programs to the ListBox control
            recentProgramsListBox.ItemsSource = filteredPrograms;


            // Create a SpeechSynthesizer instance
            _speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            // Retrieve user's name
            string userName = Environment.UserName ?? string.Empty;
            nameTextBlock.Text = $"Welcome back, {userName}!";

            // Say the welcome message
            SayWelcome(userName);

            // Retrieve last login time
            _lastLoginTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon%4Operational.evtx");
            lastLoginTextBlock.Text = $"{_lastLoginTime}";


            // Initialize the HttpClient
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _accessToken = string.Empty;

            // Call the InitializeSpotify method
            _ = InitializeSpotify();

            // Bind the properties to the UI elements
            DataContext = this;

            MouseDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                {
                    Activate();
                }
            };

            // Subscribe to the Activated event to bring the window to the top
            Activated += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Activate();
            };

            // Subscribe to the Deactivated event to stop speech synthesis
            Deactivated += (sender, e) =>
            {
                _speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
            };
        }

        public string TrackName
        {
            get { return _trackName; }
            private set
            {
                _trackName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TrackName));
            }
        }

        public string ArtistName
        {
            get { return _artistName; }
            private set
            {
                _artistName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ArtistName));
            }
        }

        public TimeSpan? SongDuration
        {
            get { return _songDuration; }
            private set
            {
                _songDuration = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SongDuration));
            }
        }

        public BitmapImage SongImage
        {
            get { return _songImage; }
            private set
            {
                _songImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SongImage));
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private async Task InitializeSpotify()
        {
            string clientId = "";
            string clientSecret = "";
            string tokenEndpoint = "";
            string refreshToken = "";


            try
            {
                // Build the request content
                var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "refresh_token" },
            { "refresh_token", refreshToken },
            { "client_id", clientId },
            { "client_secret", clientSecret }
        });

                // Send the request to refresh the access token
                var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, requestContent);
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var json = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
                _accessToken = json.Value<string>("access_token");

                // Start monitoring the currently playing track
                StartPlaybackListener();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLineToConsole($"An error occurred while initializing Spotify: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public class RecentProgram
        {
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public string FilePath { get; set; }
            public string ProgramName { get; set; }
        }




        private async Task StartPlaybackListener()
        {
            string playbackEndpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player";
            TimeSpan pollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); // Adjust the interval as per your requirement

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Make a GET request to retrieve the current playback state
                    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);
                    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(playbackEndpoint);
                    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseContent))
                        {
                            var responseObject = JObject.Parse(responseContent);

                            // Check if a track is currently playing
                            bool isPlaying = responseObject["is_playing"]?.Value<bool>() ?? false;
                            if (isPlaying)
                            {
                                await RetrieveAndDisplayCurrentlyPlayingTrack();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                WriteLineToConsole("No track is currently playing.");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            WriteLineToConsole("Empty response content received.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WriteLineToConsole($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WriteLineToConsole($"An error occurred during playback listening: {ex.Message}");
                    WriteLineToConsole($"Exception details: {ex.ToString()}");
                }

                await Task.Delay(pollInterval);
            }
        }






        private async Task RetrieveAndDisplayCurrentlyPlayingTrack()
        {

            string playbackEndpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing";

            try
            {
                // Make a GET request to retrieve the currently playing track
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);
                var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(playbackEndpoint);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var responseObject = JObject.Parse(responseString);

                // Retrieve the track information
                string trackName = (string)responseObject["item"]["name"];
                string artistName = (string)responseObject["item"]["artists"][0]["name"];
                TimeSpan songDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((double)responseObject["item"]["duration_ms"]);
                string imageUrl = (string)responseObject["item"]["album"]["images"][0]["url"];

                // Load the image from the URL
                BitmapImage songImage = await LoadImage(imageUrl);

                // Update the properties
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    TrackName = trackName;
                    ArtistName = artistName;
                    SongDuration = songDuration;
                    SongImage = songImage;
                });

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions that occur during track retrieval and display
                WriteLineToConsole("Failed to retrieve currently playing track.");
            }
        }




        private async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImage(string imageUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Download the image data asynchronously
                    var imageBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);

                    // Create a MemoryStream from the image data
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                    {
                        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                        bitmap.BeginInit();
                        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                        bitmap.EndInit();
                        bitmap.Freeze();
                        return bitmap;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception or display an error message
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred during image loading: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }

        private string DecodeProgramName(byte[] rawData, int offset)
        {
            const int programNameOffset = 56;
            const int programNameLength = 72;

            byte[] encodedName = new byte[programNameLength];
            Array.Copy(rawData, offset + programNameOffset, encodedName, 0, programNameLength);

            string programName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedName).TrimEnd('\0');
            return programName;
        }


        internal static class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            internal static extern bool DeleteObject([In] IntPtr hObject);
        }


        public class Program
        {
            public string ProgramName { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastUsedDate { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }


        private void SayWelcome(string userName)
        {
            string welcomeMessage = $"Welcome back, {userName}! I'm your personal assistant. How can I assist you today?";
            _speechSynthesizer.Speak(welcomeMessage);
        }


        //  private void WriteLineToConsole(string message)
        // {
        //     consoleTextBox.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
        //     consoleTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
        // }


        private void WriteLineToConsole(string message) { }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // Dispose the SpeechSynthesizer instance
            _speechSynthesizer?.Dispose();

            // Dispose the HttpClient instance
            _httpClient?.Dispose();
        }

        private void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {
                switch (e.Key)
                {
                    case Key.C:
                        // Handle Ctrl+C here
                        e.Handled = true;
                        break;
                    case Key.V:
                        // Handle Ctrl+V here
                        e.Handled = true;
                        break;
                    case Key.A:
                        // Handle Ctrl+X here
                        e.Handled = true;
                        break;
                        // Add more cases for other shortcuts as needed
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Could someone please guide me on how to fetch the recently used programs and bind them to the ListBox control in my C# WPF application? Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried this:

```
            string recentProgramsKey = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs";
            RegistryKey recentProgramsRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(recentProgramsKey);
            string[] recentPrograms = recentProgramsRegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames();

            recentProgramsListBox.ItemsSource = null;

            // Filter the list to show only applications
            // Filter the list to show only applications
            var applicationExtensions = new[] { ".exe" };
            var filteredPrograms = recentPrograms
                .Where(program => applicationExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(program)))
                .Select(program =>
                {
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent), program);
                    string programName = DecodeProgramName(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), 0);
                    return new RecentProgram
                    {
                        FileName = program,
                        FilePath = filePath,
                        ProgramName = programName
                    };
                })
                .ToArray();


            // Bind the filtered list of recently used programs to the ListBox control
            recentProgramsListBox.ItemsSource = filteredPrograms;
```

and I expected it to work

Comment: You should avoid System.Drawing in a WPF application as it uses a different rendering engine (GDI+) than WPF (DirectX). System.Drawing is part of the Windows Forms framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the registry for the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache` key:

```cs
RegistryKey? registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache");
if (registryKey is null)
{
  this.ListBox.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
  return;
}

IEnumerable<string> mostRecentApplicationPaths = registryKey.GetValueNames();
IEnumerable<string> applicationNames = mostRecentApplicationPaths
  .Select(path => registryKey.GetValue(path))
  .Cast<string>();

// Show application paths
this.ListBox.ItemsSource = mostRecentApplicationPaths;

// Show application display names
this.ListBox.ItemsSource = mostRecentApplicationNames;
```